# Geopy: catch timeout error

Tags: python, scrapy, geopy

I am using geopy to geocode some addresses and I want to catch the timeout errors and print them out so I can do some quality control on the input. I am putting the geocode request in a try/catch but it's not working. Any ideas on what I need to do?

Here is my code:

```
try:
  location = geolocator.geocode(my_address)               
except ValueError as error_message:
  print("Error: geocode failed on input %s with message %s"%(a, error_message))
```

I get the following exception:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/base.py", line 158, in _call_geocoder
    raise GeocoderTimedOut('Service timed out')
    geopy.exc.GeocoderTimedOut: Service timed out
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are catching the wrong exception; the exception you need to catch is `GeocoderTimedOut`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try this:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy.exc import GeocoderTimedOut

my_address = '1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW Washington, DC 20500'

geolocator = Nominatim()
try:
    location = geolocator.geocode(my_address)
    print(location.latitude, location.longitude)
except GeocoderTimedOut as e:
    print("Error: geocode failed on input %s with message %s"%(my_address, e.message))
```

You can also consider increasing the timeout on the geocode call you are making to your geolocator. In my example it would be something like:

```
location = geolocator.geocode(my_address, timeout=10)
```

or

```
location = geolocator.geocode(my_address, timeout=None)
```

Comment: Just a note, the message inside `e` in the GeocoderTimedOut error seems to be `.message` now instead of `.msg`

Answer (score 7):

I dealt with the Same Problem for so many days this is my code:

```
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="ny_explorer")
location = geolocator.geocode(address_venue)
```

**ERROR**
 Service timed out

solution:  Add a new attribute that declares the timeout:

```
location = geolocator.geocode(address_venue,timeout=10000)
```

Answer (score 5):

You may be experiencing this problem because you tried to request this address multiple times and they temporarily blocked you or slowed you down because of their [usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/).  It states no more requests than one per second and that you should cache your results.  I ran into this problem and you have a couple solutions.  If you don't want to change your code much you can get a Google API key that you can use for something like 2500 requests/day for free or you can cache your results.  Because I was already using DynamoDB on AWS for my problem I went ahead and just created a table that I cache my results in.  [Here is the gist of my code.](https://gist.github.com/tylerjw/81fb59b53da6c2de1f295f3f0e22d75c)

Answer (score 0):

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='xyz', timeout=200)
```

adding timeout will resolve the issue