# Using Geopy to convert list of addresses to GPS coordinates

Tags: python, geopy

I know how to use geopy to convert a single address to GPS coordinates, but am having trouble with my code which should read addresses line by line from a file and convert each one to GPS coordinates and print them out.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()

f = open("FILE PATH")
line = f.readline()

for line in f.readlines():
    address = line
    location = geolocator.geocode(address)
    print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
f.close()
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: http://imgur.com/LIIbg4m

That's what the console is giving me.

Comment: First, you're assigning the first line of `f` to the variable `line` and basically dismissing the value by reading the rest of the file. Second, the file handler `f` can be iterated over on itself like `for address in f:`. Third, does the code produce any results prior to the error?

Comment: It doesn't produce anything. How should I go about fixing it? This is now what I currently have: http://imgur.com/QHt7v5v

Comment: Try the answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27914648/geopy-catch-timeout-error

Comment: This is my code now: http://imgur.com/5F775v7

However, now it's just printing "Timed Out" for every address in the file

Comment: Do these addresses work individually or directly from the interpreter? The format may be off. It seems that the timeout is the reaction geopy has to addresses it can't resolve.

Comment: I tried the default address from the geopy documentation on the github page and even that address timed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
from geopy import Nominatim
import time


geolocator = Nominatim()

with open("addresses",'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        location = geolocator.geocode(line)
        # print (location.latitude, location.longitude)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: If you're going to do something like this, note that Nominatim's usage policy only allows a maximum of 1 request per second (unless you are using your own Nominatim instance): https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/. You could add a `time.sleep(1)` in the `for` loop to stay within that requirement.